# Custom info window for GMSMarker utilising UIWebView

Tags: ios, google-maps, uiwebview

I am using the Google Map iOS SDK for a project and have run into a problem whilst trying to implement a custom info window for a GMSMarker object.  I have followed the Google video tutorial but instead of using A UILabel and UIImage, I am placing a UIWebView in the UIView as this will display HTML formatted text.  However, when I run the code the  UIWebView is always blank.  If I replace with A UILabel the info window works.  Has anyone else tried to use a UIWebView like this with the iOS SDK?  I am wondering if it's related to the UIWebView taking too long to render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last I checked the info window had to be a static uiview as it is rendered to an image. (same as markers are not UIViews but only static images)

the way I do it:

return an empty transparent view to the GMSMapView and THEN:
**roll your own that you add as a subview yourself!**

This link show what I described:
https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/GoogleMapsCalloutView

Comment: Out of interest, what did you do about the user switching orientation?  Did you implement a didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation delegate method to correct the view frame or just disable switching?

Comment: we don't have switching . but I guess i'd deselect any annotation when willRotate of my viewController gets called

Comment: maybe select it again after rotation